# Cuenta caducada en Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, cuenta-usuario

Es una pregunta de lo mas novata que hay, pero no se conseguir desbloquear la cuenta.

Y la pregunta es que he puesto la caducidad de una cuenta justamente este mes (mayo) el 1 de 2021, y esa cuenta era una cuenta administrador. Necesito la cuenta ahora porque si no, no puede ejercer modificaciones.

He usado `Sudo usermod -e 2021-05-01 administrador` y para desbloquear he usado `usermod -U administrador`. Después de haber hecho esto dije, pues se "desbloqueara", pero en modo texto pongo su nombre de cuenta y contraseña, y vuelve a salirme la pantalla de login.

Y en modo grafico pone que tengo la cuenta caducada.

Lo que he hecho, para al menos desbloquear, es ir a una cuenta creada usar `su root` y poner `usermod -U administrador`. Pero como os digo la cuenta sigue caducada, y no entiendo porque sigue caducada y ya no se como desbloquearla.

Comment: Prueba con `usermod -e administrador`. Sin argumento debería sacar la fecha de caducidad.

Comment: Al poner el comando solo me sale `usermod: fecha "administrador" incorrecta`

Comment: Ups, parece que es `usermod -e "" administrador`

Comment: Al parecer no me devuelve información, solo me sale `usermod: sin cambios`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haz un status, para saber si realmente está caducada la cuenta:

```
passwd --status cuenta
```

Si estuviera bloqueada aparecería la indicación "L" o "LK" de "locked"

```
cuenta L 05/01/2021 0 99999 7 -1
```

Con el comando "change" veremos la información de la fecha

```
chage -l cuenta
```

Saldría algo así como:

```
Last password change     : May 01, 2021
Password expires     : never
Password inactive     : never
Account expires      : May 01, 2021
Minimum number of days between password change  : 0
Maximum number of days between password change  : 1
Number of days of warning before password expires : 12
```

En el caso de que haya expirado, puedes ampliar los días que necesites o desees (30 por ejemplo)

```
chage -E $(date -d +30days +%Y-%m-%d) cuenta
```

Y compruebas si los cambios han dado resultado

```
chage -l cuenta
```

Comment: Vale, después de comentar la pregunta he podido acceder a la cuenta administrador estando en el modo tipo texto.
¿motivos? los desconozco, he podido acceder a ella sin entender porque o como...

Answer (score 0):

Vale, he puesto:

```
passwd --status administrador
```

Aparece

```
administrador P 05/07/2021 0 1000 7 -1
```

No aparece la "L " o "LK", pero aun así la cuenta sigue diciendo que esta caducada.

uso chage

```
chage -l administrador
```

y me dice

```
Ultimo cambio de contraseña                                 : may 07, 2021
La contraseña caduca                                : feb 01, 2024
Contraseña inactiva                                 : nunca
La cuenta caduca                                            : nunca
Numero de días mínimo entre cambio de contraseña            : 0
Numero de días máximo entre cambio de contraseña            : 1000
Numero de días de aviso antes de que caduque la contraseña  : 7
```

He de decir que he cambiado algunos valores en el fichero `/etc/shadow` después de caducarla, y el valor modificado es el numero de días máximo entre cambio de contraseña, pero ¿eso le afecta? después de todo esto la cuenta sigue estando caducada.

Me metí anteriormente estando caducada en `/etc/shadow` y en `/etc/passwd` y la cuenta administrador no aparecía, ahora al desbloquearla si.
Espero que la información que he dado sirva de algo.

**PD**: He podido acceder a la cuenta, no entiendo como lo he conseguido.
He puesto los comandos dichos anteriormente, salgo de la sesión de un usuario creado entrando con `su root` y logeo con administrador y entro.
Cuando hace un momento no podia...

**Señores y señoras de stackoverflow, muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda :D**